# How to use header files to include functions and variables from different files

Tags: c, global-variables, header-files

I have a program that consists in three files `01.h`, `main.c`, `01.c`.

`01.h` is:

```
int b;
void jumbo();
```

`01.c` is:

```
#include "01.h"
int main()
{
    //some code
    b = 7;
    //some code
}
// some code
void jumbo()
{
//some code
}
```

`main.c` is:

```
#include "01.h"

int main()
{
    // some code
    printf(" %d", b);
    jumbo();
}
```

I am encountering two problems:

- value of `b` printed is `0` in `main.c` instead of `7`.
- On calling `jumbo()` in `main.c` the compiler shows following error:

> - main.c:|| undefined reference to `jumbo'|
> - ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|

What am I doing wrong and how can I use header files to include functions and variables from different files?

Comment: You can't have 2 main functions

Comment: @anastaciu, But the header file being included and It does not have a main function.

Comment: Alright, I answered the question see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined reference to `jumbo` is more than likely because you don't include `01.c` in your compilation.

When you include the header `01.h` you are only including the function prototype, you are *promising* the compiler that a function exists with that name, arguments, and return type. When the code is compiled the compiler will look for such implementation, if it doesn't find it, it can't compile the program because it has no *knowledge* of what such function should do.

To *really* include the function implementation you need to compile and link the file where the function is implemented, in this case `01.c`.

Now if you do that you'll have a new error which will be something along the lines of `multiple definitions of main`.

What you need to do is to remove the `main` implementaion from `01.c` and include this file in your compilation process, it would look something like this:

**01.h:**

```
int b = 7; // normally you wouldn't do this, in headers is usual to define constants only
           // b is indeed a global variable and these should only 
           // be used if you absolutely have to
void jumbo();
```

**main.c:**

```
#include "01.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // some code
    printf(" %d", b);
    jumbo();
}
```

**01.c:**

```
// here you don't need to include 01.h
void jumbo()
{
    //some code
}
```

This is a possible compilation command with `gcc`:

```
 gcc main.c 01.c -o program_name
            ^^^^
```

You can add some routine warning flags to detect potential problems in your code:

```
gcc main.c 01.c -o program_name -Wall -Wextra -pedantic   
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**[Here you have a live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KbupRLPMNVaFJsLp)**

Comment: I was not including the file 01.c in compilation but it was in the same directory.

Comment: @EMS some IDEs do the work for us, others don't, still is nice to know how things work in the background. I trust you solved the problem, if not let me know.

Comment: Problem was solved when I compiled them together.

Answer (score 0):

See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website. Then read some C11 standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and enable all warnings and debug info when compiling. If you use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, invoke it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You could use later the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

You may want to:

- declare `extern int b;` in header file `01.h`
- define `int b;` in one implementation file, e.g. in `main.c`

Of course, you should have only one `main` function.

Take inspiration from the source code of some existing C open source software, e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Don't forget to read the documentation of your C compiler and source code editor (e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) and debugger.

For real-life programs, do document (with a pencil and paper, or using [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/)) the software architecture, and some coding conventions. See the [GTK](http://gtk.org/) project for an example.

You could want to use [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) to generate *some* documentation from comments formatted in a specified way.

You could want to use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).